# Passing variable from php to javascript - follow-up

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I saw this post [Passing a variabe to jquery using Odometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969431/passing-a-variabe-to-jquery-using-odometer) but am unable to comment on it. I had a follow-up question.

Hoping I can get an answer.

I am using this php to pull a value from mysql:

```
<?php


// Make a MySQL Connection
include("/home/www/php_snippets/dbconnect.php");

//execute the SQL query and return records
$query = "SELECT total_miles, SUM(total_miles) FROM mileage as total_miles"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "Total Miles". $row['type']. " = ". $row['SUM(total_miles)'];
    echo "<br />";
}

//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

I want to use this script to put this value on my page:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                //Get the value from serverside
                var uid = '<%=odometervalue  %>';
                odometer.innerHTML = uid;
            }, 1000);
        });
</script>
```

The solution says to use a puplic string to declare the variable but I am confused where to use it. In my PHP?

> You can use the below implementation to pass the value from code behind to Jquery
>   This is one example how to do it.
>   First Declare a Public Variable in code behind
>   //Declare a Public Variable in code behind

```
public string odometervalue = "667";
```

Could I use:

```
public string odometervalue = total_miles;
```

In my above php?
I am still learning so please assist if you can :)

Comment: Is your PHP code and javascript code in the same file?

Comment: People, stop using `mysql_` . It's officialy deprecated as of PHP 5.5 . Use `mysqli_`. https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation

Comment: in your JS: var someString = <?php echo $thePHPvariable; ?>;  assuming the php code is in the same page as the JS script

Comment: php and js are in different files. I suppose I could try embedding the js in the main php.. hmmmm

Comment: also to complicate it more, it is a WordPress dite. i am ussing php snippets to include my php.

Comment: Another thing to mention, the variable `odometervalue` that you are trying to display in JS is not declared anywhere in your PHP script. You also forgot the prefix you php variable name with $ sign.

Comment: Thanks Amaynut. So in my php i woudl use public string $odometervalue = total_miles; ????